# Передача параметров PHP из jquery step basic в скрипт

Tags: php, jquery

Установил базовый скрипт jquery step basic example

В js/jquery.steps.js прописал следующее:

```html
onFinished: function (event, currentIndex)  
                    {
                        window.location.href = "test_insert.php";  
                    }
```

Переходить - переходит, а позже я понял, что window.location.href - никаких данных не передает. Ни GET ни POST

Как тогда передать данные методом POST к файлу "test_insert.php"? При коде указанном ниже не происходит ни переадресация, ни передача данных.

```html
onFinished: function (event, currentIndex)
                    {
                            type: "POST";
    url: "test_insert.php";
                    },
```

Comment: Вам нужно перейти на php-скрипт с параметрами или все же отправить ему параметры и получить от него ответ в этой же странице?

Comment: GET передается запросто. window.location.href = "test_insert.php?var1="+var1+"&var2="+var2;

Comment: Перейти на скрипт с PHP параметрами. Это модуль заявок, которые содержат в себе ФИО, телефон, email, пару тестирующих вопросов. 
Я рассматриваю POST запрос, т.к. данные будут заносится в базу.

Comment: если вам сначала надо показать форму с вопросами, то вы гет-запрашиваете эту форму, а там уже пост-отправляете. Если надо устроить из js программную отправку пост в основном потоке, то создается `<form method="post"` и отправляется программно.

Comment: В JS я прописываю
onFinished: function (event, currentIndex) {
  $("#finish").submit();

В html - 
<form action="test.php" method="post">
            <div id="wizard">
...
</form>
И перехода, редиректа не происходит.
Что я делаю не так, если программно я все делаю?